# Azure ADF pipeline not able to connect to Azure SQL

Tags: azure

I am trying to run a ADF pipeline and it has to do Copy Data activity, but the linked service (Azure SQL Database) is throwing error.

**Connection failed**

Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433', Database: 'xxx', User: 'xxx'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.), SqlErrorNumber=11001,Class=20,State=0,
No such host is known
Activity ID: xxx.
This may happen if your data source only allows secured connections. If that's the case, please use a VNet integration runtime.

Comment: Check the firewall and see that azure service must have access to sql database

Answer (score 0):

I think the Azure SQL Firewall needs to be updated or allow azure services to communicate in Azure SQL Firewall. I think that should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the SQL firewall rules are already opted for "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" and still its not able to connect. Do I need to provide any kind of authorization somewhere in Azure portal

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternative

1. by using [Manage Private End Point](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-connect-azure-data-factory-to-an-azure-sql-database-using-a-private-endpoint-3e46984bec5e) but in this case your Azure
   SQL only have **Private Access** between ADF and Azure SQL.
2. by using **Exception**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Allow azure services and resources to access this server.]

Go to Azure SQL find "set the firewall option",
Select Allow Azure services and resources to access this server.
And add the IP address highlighted to the firewall rule.

This solves your problem. Happy coding.